# Does installing Python also install libraries like scipy and numpy?

Tags: python

I just got a new computer, and I was installing some Python libraries. When I tried to install numpy, I got a message on the console saying numpy was already downloaded. I went into the library folder, and not only was numpy there, but scipy, matplotlib, and a bunch of other libraries as well. How is this possible, considering this computer is brand new? I had installed Python the previous evening, so does installing Python automatically install these libraries as well?

Comment: depending on how you install python, it comes with a bunch of libraries packaged together with it. An especially useful distribution is Anaconda, for example, which comes with just about every library you'd need to start with and then some.

Comment: Yeah, I literally just downloaded it from the Python website

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: MacOS Mojave, brand new computer, no files copied from another one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which Python package you install.

On any desktop oriented Linux distribution, installing the Python package will only install Python. And in practice, it is generally already installed.

On Windows (and perhaps OS X), you need to pick a Python bundle somewhere. Perhaps did you choose [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), which AFAIK installs a lot of common Python libraries (as opposed to its light version [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)).

Comment: I installed from the Python website. Would these libraries be bundled here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/

Comment: No they wouldn't. Perhaps at some point after the Python install you installed a package that depends on these data science libraries.

Comment: The only thing I installed after this was pip

Comment: How did you install pip?

Comment: I used Easy install

Comment: To answer you question, no, installing Python binaries from https://www.python.org/ then pip should not install numpy and all. So there must be something else.

Comment: I don’t see how there could be anything else, it’s a brand new computer

Comment: @JackCeroni that's strange. PIP already comes with the Python interpreter since forever.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what’s going on. It’s probably because I was trying to use pip not pip3, which was probably already installed, but I still don’t understand how numpy scipy and matplotlib got on the device

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not the place for these types of questions, yes, there is no need to install libraries, as most of the times when you download Python in a distribution, such as Anaconda, they are also included.

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to Stackexchange, where should this question be asked?

Comment: This is not correct. If you just download Python, you won't have all these libraries included as standard

Comment: Edited, forgot to mention the package.

Comment: I downloaded it from the Python website: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/

Comment: I would recommend you delete your download and install this package, as it is a better option than the one you installed: https://www.anaconda.com/download/ . Hope this helps, and don't forget to select an answer that you feel adressed your concerns, and up vote any others that you have found usefull!

Comment: The word you are looking for is *Python distribution*, not python *package*.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not ship with these libraries unless you are using a pre-packaged distribution such as Anaconda.

Comment: I just downloaded from the Python website here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/

Comment: Then you may have installed a package that depends on these libraries (many do). You can easily try yourself and make a fresh install. Please consider selecting an answer if you feel like your question has been adressed.

Answer (score 1):

If you copied your data from your previous computer to this one, you may have copied the python installation (and thereby the libraries you had installed before) in your appdata folder.

Another possibility is that you have install Anaconda, which is targeted especially at scientific things, and comes with numpy, scipy and some other things preinstalled.